# Why is Next.js adding a ?ts query parameter to static JS files, preventing loading them from cache?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

On every page load, Next.js requests the same JS files with a query parameter such as `?ts=1234`.

E.g:

```
/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1671033077175
/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1671033077175
```

This is obviously done to prevent reusing these files from the browser cache. But I want to reuse them since they are the same until a rebuild is deployed.

Why is this parameter added?

If it is to prevent using outdated code after a rebuild, then why not have a build version as the value instead of a timestamp?

Are there any available configuration options for caching static JS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp query parameter is added only in development mode, i.e. if you start the next.js app with:

```
npx next dev
```

To start a production build, run:

```
npx next build
npx next start
```

This will allow caching of all JS files, as well as make them much leaner and faster by removing all of the development and debug tools.

Comment: So how can we keep timestamp or version in production build ?
trying to avoid cache issue when do new builds